# "It's a bit terrifying doing something" vs "It's a bit terrifying to do something"

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

I am wondering which one of the following is grammatically correct? Or maybe both are grammatically correct but they mean different things?

> It is terrifying to explore the world, not knowing where one will end up.
>
> It is terrifying exploring the world, not knowing where one will end up.

Comment: They're both fine. The first version is a bit more formal but the meaning is the same.

Comment: Could you give me more analysis and possibly more examples contrasting the differences? It would be great if you can mention some references.